# How to set default values after Register and Simple Membership vs Other #MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multiplayer

I'm working with a multiplayer environment, Coding using the MVC4 framework, C#

I don't understand how to get access to the register button in the account controller, I want to have a method which sets default values once a user clicks register. Do I make another method to set these values or where do I edit the Register method?

And also, I'm using the simple membership set up, are they any other MVC specific login methods to use, and how will I be able to pick up which user is logged in? Cause I am working with a multiplayer environment.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you've created an internet application in MVC your account controller will contain a register method.

if not add

**

```
 [HttpGet] public ActionResult Register()  {
     if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
     {
         WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UserDb", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
     }
    return View();
```

}

```
 [HttpPost] public ActionResult Register(FormCollection form) {
>     WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(form["username"], form["password"], new{DisplayName = form["displayname"],
> Country=form["country"]});
>     Response.Redirect("~/account/login");
>     return View(); }

**
```

You can set default values here, if your storing data to a db then you will need to connect to your context and add data to the various fields in the tables your setting data for.

OR

you can create a class/ method and call it up to initialize values.

I recommend using Asp.Net Identities to Simple Membership